# How to define network interface

Tags: kaa

I'm developing Kaa. i don't understand this part:
$ sudo nano /etc/kaa-node/conf/kaa-node.properties
transport_public_interface=localhost=YOUR_PUBLIC_INTERFACE
the link is :http://kaaproject.github.io/kaa/docs/v0.10.0/Administration-guide/System-installation/Single-node-installation/

how to define YOUR_PUBLIC_INTERFACE ?

Answer (score 1):

You should not define this as a variable. Just replace *YOUR_PUBLIC_INTERFACE* with the correct interface name.

Answer (score 1):

`YOUR_PUBLIC_INTERFACE` means the public IP or DNS where the Kaa server runs.
For  example the entry in property file will be as follows
`transport_public_interface=54.17.30.158`